# Integration JAMES Apache and Thunderbird

Tags: apache, email, smtp, imap, james

I have been figuring out and successfully configured JAMES Apache server. I am currently using this version: james-server-app-3.0.0-beta5-SNAPSHOT

So now I added two users using james-cli -h localhost -p 9999 user1 password
and user2 password

All this is successful.

I added a domain is captcha.com

I also added to /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 imap.captcha.com
127.0.0.1 smtp.captcha.com

This is also sucessful.

I proceed to thunderbird and did some configuration. I added a SMTP server which is on port 25.

I added the two users both using incoming mail imap.captcha.com port 143 and outgoing smtp.captcha.com port 25.

Oh by the way I also set up JAMES apache with MySQL database using database.properties this is also successfully done.

Finally here comes the question, Im sorry for the long winded stories above.

I sent 3 mails from user1 to user2 and in order to check the mails, i need to log in. Log in is successfully done on both users but it seems like I am not able to see any emails received. I check the folder C:\james-server-app-3.0.0-beta5-20150626.101708-1075-app\james-server-app-3.0.0-beta5-SNAPSHOT\var\store\activemq\blob-transfer

In my database, mailbox has also some information inputted by JAMES.

In this folder there is a lot of other folders 1, 2, 6, 9 and inside the folders are some file names ID_PC-50379-1459500692647-4_1_13_1_2 which I do not understand.

May I know what is blob-transfer and why can't I receive the mails from user1 to user2? I have been trying my best to find resources online but there is nothing much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution via http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/james/james.html
I am currently using 2.3.1 and it is a better and stable version but also some problems I am facing now is MySQL database. So following mobilefish will easily let you set up the server and send mails here and there.